# Mouse callback Function

Tags: python

I have the following code:

```
drawing = False # true if mouse is pressed
mode = True # if True, draw rectangle. Press 'm' to toggle to curve
ix,iy = -1,-1

# mouse callback function
def draw_circle(event,x,y,flags,param):
    global ix,iy,drawing,mode

    if event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN:
        drawing = True
        ix,iy = x,y

    elif event == cv2.EVENT_MOUSEMOVE:
        if drawing == True:
            if mode == True:
                cv2.rectangle(img,(ix,iy),(x,y),(0,255,0),-1)
            else:
                cv2.circle(img,(x,y),20,(0,0,255),-1)

    elif event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONUP:
        drawing = False
        if mode == True:
            cv2.rectangle(img,(ix,iy),(x,y),(0,255,0),-1)
        else:
            cv2.circle(img,(x,y),20,(0,0,255),-1)
```

I don't understand the use of `xi` and `yi` on the rectangle. There is a line which stated that `xi,yi = x,y`. Would it be the same? How would it draw rectangle? From what I understand, to draw a rectangle, there should be two sets of coordinates. I can't see which part in the line that shows that `ix,iy` will be different with x and y value.

Can anyone explain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its pretty straightforward here is what happens in steps:

the user clicks down - current mouse position x,y is stored as ix,iy and drawing is set to true

the user moves the mouse - if drawing is true and mode is true draws a rectangle using the saved ix,iy and the new current x,y (note that ix,iy does NOT equal x,y anymore since its only saved when the mouse button down triggers)

the user releases the mouse - drawing is set to false so the mouse can be moved without drawing anything and any current images are saved

Comment: can you explain the use of param and flags? as it does not appear in any line. Btw, thanks for the explanation

Comment: @SyariaeShahzaman are you asking about the parameters of the functions of opencv ? and the events ?

Comment: @SyariaeShahzaman also you're welcome! Would you consider upvoting / checking it as the accepted answer if it helped you out ?

Comment: how do i upvoting? i am new with this. yeah. About my second question, is in the draw circlr function  there is variables of flags and param. what that does?